# How to open a file from buffer in a split window?

Tags: vim, vi

I've two files say, *file1.txt* and *file2.txt* added to buffer in vim.
I've currently opened *file1.txt* and I know that the command `:b2` opens *file2.txt* from the buffer.

But, I would like to open *file2.txt* in the split window, keeping *file1.txt*.
Is there a way to do it, without using the commands such as `:vs file2.txt` ?
I am looking for a command which operates on buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:sb2
```

opens buffer #2 in an horizontal window.

```
:vert sb2
```

opens buffer #2 in a vertical window.

```
:tab sb2
```

opens buffer #2 in a new tab page.

`:sb` is 12 lines below `:help :b` so… try a little harder next time.

Comment: @mps if you didn't read help doc carefully, you should at least read the answer carefully.  btw, you could use `sba` for all buffers, in this way, you don't need check which buffer number the next file is.

Comment: May I know why the comment: "you should at least read the answer carefully"?

Comment: I think you need to mention @Kent in your comment.

Comment: @mps you posted a comment for asking "how to do the split vertically" which was clearly explained by romainl in answer, that's why I wrote that sentence. later you removed your comment.

Comment: @Kent The answer initially didn't explain vertical split

Comment: @mps maybe we were reading the post on different time and this made some misunderstanding. I say sorry if it made you unhappy. I cannot edit the comment any longer.

Comment: @Kent Ya, that could be the reason. It happens don't worry.